# class vs addClassName jscript

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

what is the difference, in using class vs addClassName jscript?

in a for loop, whenever I was adding a class to the existing class, then after each loop cycle it was adding new class to it. So condition to enter the loop was changing after each time.

when I used class instead of addClassName then everything started to work as it should be. Which is after each reverse session the loop was matching the condition.

How it can be explained?

WORKING VERSION:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) //instead of .each
    {
            alert(0.5);
            alert(fields[i].className);


        if (fields[i].className == 'text' || fields[i].className == 'date' || fields[i].className == 'number' || fields[i].className == 'text error' || fields[i].className == 'date error' || fields[i].className == 'number error' || fields[i].className == 'text valid' || fields[i].className == 'date valid' || fields[i].className == 'number valid' || fields[i].className == 'text valid error' || fields[i].className == 'date valid error' || fields[i].className == 'number valid error' )
        {
        alert(0.3);

        var val = fields[i];        


        var classname = "";
        if(val.value.length <= 4) {
            classname = fields[i].className + " error";


            fields[i].class = classname;

            Effect.Shake(fields[i], { times:3 }, 50);
            errorString = 'Please complete all required fields.';

           alert(0.6);
           alert(val.value);
           alert(0.66);
           alert(fields[i].name);
           alert(val.value.class);
           //error++;
        }  


        else {

            classname = fields[i].className + " valid";
            fields[i].class = classname;
            alert(8.5);
           alert(val.value.class);

        }

        } 
        alert(8.8);
            alert(fields[i].class); 
    }
```

VERSION WHICH IS NOT WORKING:

```
            for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) //instead of .each
    {

        if (fields[i].className == 'text' || fields[i].className == 'date' ||      fields[i].className == 'number' || fields[i].className == 'text error' || fields[i].className == 'date error' || fields[i].className == 'number error' )
        {
        var val = fields[i];        



        if(val.value.length <= 4) {             
            fields[i].addClassName('error');

            Effect.Shake(fields[i], { times:3 }, 50);
            errorString = 'Please complete all required fields.';

            error++;
        } else {
            fields[i].addClassName('valid');

        }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Have some code to show us what's going on?

Comment: In JS you set classes with the `className` property, not `class`. Please show some code that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: if I submit and then press back button, then the transition of the first snippet works, but it voids adding the class :-)

Comment: how can I add a valid or error class to the element without compromising loop session?

Comment: @d689p: are the answers explanative enough, or do you expect anything else?

Comment: sorry Jan, not clearly understand what you mean

Comment: I expect the code to check for the empty fields and if it is not, then give a green border('valid' - class), else to give a red border ('error' - class). And you see the issue is when those elements go thru the loop, then an 'error' class is added, and in order to qualify for the loop next time - I have to add a new condition to IF, such as 'error date' and next time 'error date valid'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Explanation

`class` is a [reserved keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words) (for possible future use), therefore it should not be used as object attribute (like `someobject.reservedKeyword`) and therefore `className` instead of `class` is used as nnnnnn points out in the comment to your question.

In your code, this won't work:

```
fields[i].class = classname
```

...but this one will

```
fields[i].className = classname
```

This is the source code of prototypejs `addClassName`

```
function addClassName(element, className) {
    if (!(element = $(element))) return;

    if (!hasClassName(element, className))
      element.className += (element.className ? ' ' : '') + className;

    return element;
}
```

see [the prototypejs link](https://github.com/sstephenson/prototype/blob/ecacc02/src/prototype/dom/dom.js#L2448)

### Solution

Therefore use `addClassName`, `removeClassName` and `hasClassName`. In your code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
    if(fields[i].hasClassName("text") || fields[i].hasClassName("number") || fields[i].hasClassName("date")) {
        if(fields[i].value.length<=4) {
            fields[i].addClassName("error");
            fields[i].removeClassName("valid");
            Effect.Shake(fields[i], { times:3 }, 50);
            errorString = 'Please complete all required fields.';
        }
        else {
            fields[i].addClassName("valid");
            fields[i].removeClassName("error");
        }
    }
}
```

Note: in [modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=classList) we use `classList` attribute instead:

```
prototype.js                         | modern browsers
---------------------------------------------------------------------
element.hasClassName("someclass")    | element.classList.contains("someclass")
element.addClassName("someclass")    | element.classList.add("someclass")
element.removeClassName("someclass") | element.classList.remove("someclass")
```

Comment: you're the man! Great stuff, I did not have a clue, that there is also hasClassName property. Thank you very much.

Comment: hey Jan, you seem to have an interesting personal website, but unfortunately I could not understand Czech language, although I know Russian. I see you do some critical analyses on the topics of your interest, nice one. Would be nice to see it in English some day.

Comment: Thank you. There are plenty of English resources, but Czech (Russian or any other language) localized stuff is uncommon, so I wrote some minimal handbook for my students. If I grow up enough to match the level of the wise guys here on SO, I will publish some accepted stuff.

Answer (score 0):

[`addClassName`](http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/dom/Element/addClassName/index.html) is the prototypejs way of adding a class to an HTML element.

If you have been assigning to `$('something').class` what you did is add a property to that object in particular, each time you set it to that object it would be replaced, if you create a new object that refers to the same element it will not have that property and - of course - it will not be tied to the class of the HTML element.